# Why don't two inline-blocks line up to the top in parent wrapper div?

Tags: html, css

I have my HTML like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#main {
    width: 790px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 170px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hpwff/

The problem is that even though the sum of both divs is 960px, which is the same width as the parent container's (#wrapper), they do not float next to each other. I have to shrink either the sidebar or main containers width back by 4px so they fit. Why is this, and is there a way around it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a newline between the two `div`s; since they are `inline-block`, the newline between them is rendered as a space. [Without space](http://jsfiddle.net/Hpwff/2/) it works as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Add float: left; to each div and it works like it should! [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hpwff/1/)

Updated code:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#main {
    width: 790px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 170px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

Look this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hpwff/3/). You need to add float: left to your main and sidebar blocks. And add clear block after them.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        <p>test</p>
    </div><div id="sidebar">
        <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

No space between `</div>` and `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the older tricks - you need to set the font size of the wrapping container (#wrapper) to 0px and then each of the children to whatever the font size you require.

This trick works on almost all browsers. However, this time it is not IE, but rather Safari that is failing to acknowledge the setup.

So the code should look like this:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    font-size:0px;
}

#main {
    width: 790px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size:16px;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 170px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size:16px;
}​
```

You can test it on your already created jsfiddle, it works well.